# Finding duplicate Values with SHACL and SPARQL

Tags: duplicates, sparql, shacl

I am relatively new to shacl and sparql and stuck with a problem.

I have an ontology which contains information about factory plant.

A part of this ontology is the description of room as individuals.
The individuals can be created by any person and I need to check now if their creation is valid. e.g The room-name is in a giving pattern, the floor number is an integer.....

I'm writing this validation in shacl but stuck.

How can I check if a room number is already existing in the ontology?
The room number is defined as a data property over "hasRoomNr".

Shortform: I want to find duplicate values and create an error.

I'm working with protege and read a lot about shacl. Also that it is not directly possible to compare data values.

My plan is now to combine shacl and sparql to write a query to search for that. But I am stuck to compare values. I managed to write a sparql query which gives me all the room numbers.

Now I need to find a way to compare them and create a validations report out off interferences.

Is it even possible to do it?

Comment: it would be easier if you show data + current SPARQL query and/or SHACL constraint. in SPARQL `select distinct ?n {?s1 :hasRoomNr ?n . ?s2 :hasRoomNr ?n . filter(?s1 != ?s2)}` returns room numbers used by multiple entities

Comment: > I'm working with protege and read a lot about shacl. Also that it is not directly possible to compare data values.  

Correct: this is not the kind of question SHACL usually answers (you would have to do something advanced like define your own function) as SHALC's all about "shapes" of data, not instances really.  

> My plan is now to combine shacl and sparql to write a query to search for that.  

You can easily create a SHACL file that triggers a SPARQL query, see the SHACL spec for ASK examples